# add value to struct to pointer segmentation error in C

Tags: pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

people, i've an issue now..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct a
{
 int *aa;
 int *bb;
 struct b *wakata;
}a;

typedef struct b
{
 int *you;
 int *me;
}b;

int main()
{
a *aq;
aq = (a*)malloc(sizeof(a*));

*aq->wakata->you = 1;
*aq->wakata->me = 2;

free(aq);


return 0;
}
```

and compiled, then debugged :

```
gcc -o tes tes.c --debug
sapajabole@cintajangankaupergi:/tmp$ gdb -q ./tes
Reading symbols from /tmp/tes...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/tes 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08048414 in main () at tes.c:22
22  *aq->wakata->you = 1;
```

well, the question is, how to set the value to variable inside struct 'b' through struct 'a' ?

anyone ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial allocation of `a` is only allocating 4 bytes (in a 32-bit architecture).  It should be:

```
aq = (a*)malloc(sizeof(a));
```

And `wakata` has not been initialized:  Maybe this:

```
aq->wakata = (b*)malloc(sizeof(b));
```

And it will need a corresponding free as well prior to the free of `aq`.

```
free(aq->wakata);
```

And since you have pointers to the integers, those would also need to be allocated (`you` and `me`).  But it is not clear if that is your goal.  You probably should remove the `*` from the int declarations so that they are simply `int` members rather than the pointers to int.

Comment: mm, just because a is defined as specifier, thus we do not need to put (*) inside sizeof, right ?

Comment: @capede: `a*` means "pointer to a", so it is 4 bytes.  Specifying `sizeof(a)` will be probably be 12 bytes in a 32-bit architecture.

Comment: what is mean of `pointer to a` then make it just have 4 bytes = 1 int, because there are two integer and one struct, and how come it become 12 bytes when im just using `sizeof(a)` ?

Comment: @capede: A pointer (which is a memory address) on a 32-bit machine. `sizeof` is an operator that returns the number of bytes of its operand. The structure `a` requires (most likely) 12 bytes: 4 bytes for each of the three pointers in the structure (two pointers to ints and 1 pointer to another structure).  If you remove the `*` from the ints as suggested, it will still be 12 bytes since an int in a 32-bit OS is likely to be 4 bytes.

Comment: oh i get, it on 32-bit, `pointer to something` size is 4 bytes, because `there` variable in struct a which are `two pointers to int `and `a pointer to struct`, so its `12 bytes`, wish this thought is straight :D

Comment: @capede:  Yes you are correct.  It sounds like you are getting it now.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a few mistakes here. See the code below.
In general a few things to keep in mind. You can't access memory before you malloc it. Also, there is a difference between memory and pointers e.g. int and int *

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct a
{
 int aa;
 int bb;
 struct b *wakata;
}a;

typedef struct b
{
 int you;
 int me;
}b;

int main()
{
 a * aq = malloc(sizeof(a));

 aq->wakata = malloc(sizeof(b))
 aq->wakata->you = 1;
 aq->wakata->me = 2;

 free(aq->wakata)
 free(aq);

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`wakata` isn't pointing to any valid memory.  You have to malloc memory for it, and then also for `wakata->you` and `wakata->me`

Comment: then every pointer is a must to malloc() / allocating memory, even for pointer to char (string), am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

Pointers do not contain data. They point at data. That is why they are called pointers.

When you `malloc` enough space to store an `a` instance named `aq`, you allocate space for the pointers contained in that structure. You do not cause them to point at anything, nor do you allocate space to contain the things that they would point at.

Answer (score 0):

You're not allocating space for `b` in struct `a`. You have defined 'a' as holding pointers, not structs. Also, I think malloc`(sizeof(a*))` should be `malloc(sizeof(a))`

```
aq = (a*)malloc(sizeof(a)); // You should probably use calloc here
aq->wakata = (b*)malloc(sizeof(b));
```

`you` and `me` don't seem to need to be pointers, just normal ints

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems with your code.

1. When you allocate memory for the `struct a`, you should do

   aq = (a*)malloc(sizeof(a));
2. You now allocated memory for the `struct a`, but not for the `struct b` pointed by the `wakata` member, so you need to do

   aq->wakata = (b*)malloc(sizeof(b));
3. Finally, in the `struct b` there should not be `int*` members, but `int` members. This way, you'll be able to correctly assign a value to them.

Remember that you should check for the correct allocation of memory by checking if the `malloc` return value is not `NULL`.